# Using a GroupBy Clause to sum

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query..

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(utcdt,GET_FORMAT(DATE,'ISO')) as utcdt, 
                HOUR(utcdt) as hour, 
                country,
                sum(impressions) as impressions 
                FROM rtb_impressions where campaign_id='cid2204184260'
                GROUP BY utcdt, hour, country
```

These are the results.....

```
{'impressions': Decimal('1'), 'country': 'US', 'hour': 10L, 'utcdt': '2012-10-01'}
{'impressions': Decimal('40000'), 'country': 'US', 'hour': 9L, 'utcdt': '2012-10-02'}
{'impressions': Decimal('20000'), 'country': 'US', 'hour': 9L, 'utcdt': '2012-10-02'}
```

Why did I get three rows when I should have gotten 2?  012-10-02 should have been summed.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting that because you are grouping by the wrong value.
Try this instead:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(utcdt,GET_FORMAT(DATE,'ISO')) as utcdt, 
            HOUR(utcdt) as hour, 
            country,
            sum(impressions) as impressions 
            FROM rtb_impressions where campaign_id='cid2204184260'
            GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(utcdt,GET_FORMAT(DATE,'ISO')), hour, country
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(utcdt,GET_FORMAT(DATE,'ISO')) as utcdt, 
       HOUR(utcdt) as hour, 
       country,
       sum(impressions) as impressions 
FROM rtb_impressions
WHERE campaign_id='cid2204184260'
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(utcdt,GET_FORMAT(DATE,'ISO')), hour, country
```

If you want to group results on a formatted value you need to be sure you apply the same formatting in your `GROUP BY` clause.